# Data migration from one self-hosted gitlab server to another self-hosted server

Tags: gitlab, migration

I am trying to migrate from one self hosted gitlab server to another

So ,the problem is I forgot the password of the Linux server that the gitlab is hosted on

I tried exporting group via file export but it won't export project.

I tried the direct transfer api but my old server is running below 14 version and new one was above 15 version.

I don't know how to do the migration , please help me..Thank you.

A solution on How to migrate from old gitlab server to new gitlab server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The group export does not include the projects, so you would do a group export, and then a project export for each project inside of a group.

Actually, [GitLab 15.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/04/22/gitlab-15-11-released/#migrate-gitlab-projects-by-direct-transfer-using-api) (April 2023) adds:

> ### Migrate GitLab projects by direct transfer using API
>
> Until now you could migrate GitLab projects by direct transfer only when migrating GitLab groups.
> If some projects failed to be migrated, you couldn’t try to import only failed projects again. The workaround was to import chosen projects by uploading export files, which imports only one project at a time.
>
> With this release, you can migrate projects by direct transfer using the API. >
> You can use this to re-import only the chosen failed project.
> This also lays the groundwork for this feature to be made available in the UI.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/bulk_imports.html#start-a-new-group-migration) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/390515).

Answer (score 0):

The group export does not include the projects, so you would do a group export, and then a project export for each project inside of a group.

While you can attempt to do a group/project export and import, be warned that the [documentation states this is only supported for 2 minor versions apart](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html#compatibility), so you can try it, but there's no guarantee it'll work.

If you're only interested in the repository, then you can use the [import repo by URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/repo_by_url.html).

Since the versions you're looking at are fairly far apart, you can attempt to use the [congregate tool](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/professional-services-automation/tools/migration/congregate).

If none of those work, then you could try to script something similar yourself by using the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/) to loop through all your groups and projects, the individual issues, notes, etc. and recreate them on the new GitLab instance.